# JPA annotation for mapped entity with values based on the root entity?

Tags: jpa, annotations

I'm trying to annotate my JPA-Entity. In the entity I want to map another Entity which should be loaded by values of the root entity.

Example:

Entity A has the fields key1 & key2.

I want to map Entity B which should be loaded by the filter b.key1 = a.key1 & b2.key2 = a.key2

Can anyone help?

Comment: Define EntityA and EntityB which map to the same key1/key2 DB fields. If  that's no good please post more on your scenario and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I just used @ManyToOne and @JoinColumns:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns(
{
    @JoinColumn(name="key1", referencedColumnName="refKey1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="key2", referencedColumnName="refKey2")
}
)
private EntityB entityB;
```